# How can i find source of html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I want to know form where page loads html...
For example, in my developing page I find this code

```
<div id="dnn_NavPane"><a name="alo"></a>    
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
//some code here
</table>
</div>
```

In sources I find that .ascx file, in which I see only this

```
<div runat="server" id="NavPane"></div>
```

So I about 2 hours can't find from where he feel div with that content? How can I find that code?

Here they used `DotNetNuke` and maybe secret is in that? Who can help?

Comment: Might be only JS and CSS

Comment: I take a look to all files that it gets in page loading process... And found nothing about that div...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your DotNetNuke skin has a `<div />` that is `runat=server`, that gets transformed into a "pane."  DotNetNuke allows you to add modules to the pane, so you'd need to see what module is in there to see how its markup is being generated.  It will probably be somewhere in the website's `DesktopModules` folder, and you can look it up in the "Module Definitions" or "Extensions" page (depending on the version of DNN) to see more information about a module.

If you don't have access to the running website, the assignment of a module to a pane is stored in the database.  You'll want to find the page in the `Tabs` table, then check the entries in the `TabModules` table to see what module is in that pane on that tab.  From there, follow `TabModules` to `Modules` to `ModuleDefinitions` to `ModuleControls` to see which control is generating the markup.

Answer (score 3):

If they are using DotNetNuke then the content is being dynamically generated.

You can only see `<div runat="server" id="NavPane"></div>` because the content is dynamically being added to this.

I you want to edit the html, then you will need to edit it through the DotNetNuke Content Management System.

Comment: But if DotNetNuke generates it, it must be saved in such a file, isn't i true?
Can't I change that generation code without having Content Management System?

Comment: I am not sure how DNN works as I have never used it. But if this is the Navigation Menu, then it will be created from Pages within the database that are flagged to be displayed in the menu OR there is some sort of Menu administration page which allows you to add/delete items from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

you know that server id of the element is NavPane. Go to codebehind and track all the operations with that control. try to work out when the inner html is assigned. Then attach to server process, make breakpoints there and see in debugger what happens.

> Here they used DotNetNuke and maybe secret is in that?

maybe :) if you don't know how the underlying layer works the complexity of your task grows sufficiently